# PG_DUMP via shell_exec retorna "no password supplied"

Tags: php, postgresql, shell-script

Executo com sucesso o seguinte comando pelo terminal:

`pg_dump -d teste -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres -w -f /home/william/pgsql/17032701.backup`

No entanto, quando executo o comando pelo `shell_exec` do `PHP`, tenho o seguinte retorno:

`pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "teste" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

Preciso criar uma rotina onde o usuário tenha o poder criar o backup do banco de dados através da interface do sistema. No entanto, o usuário não tem a senha (e mesmo se tivesse não seria necessário informar a mesma).

Se na linha de comando, eu retiro `-w`, em ambas as execuções (`shell_exec` e `terminal`) é necessário informar a senha para prosseguir. Mas isso é longe do meu ideal.

Em minha busca pela solução, tentei mudar as configurações do `pg_hba.config`, mas sem sucesso.

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1):

O parâmetro **-w** suprime a pergunta da senha, em contra partida o pg_dump espera que você tenha uma variável de ambiente chamada **PGPASSWORD**. Antes de executar seu script crie uma variável de ambiente PGPASSWORD com a senha.